# C# reading data off html

Tags: c#

I've been trying to see if I could get timetable data of a school website, and make a little application of it. At the moment this is what I have :

```
string userInput = "/*My username will be here*/";
string passInput = "/*My password will be here */";

string formUrl = "https://portal.gc.ac.nz/student/index.php/process-login";
string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", userInput, passInput);
string cookieHeader;

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];

string pageSource;
string getUrl = "https://portal.gc.ac.nz/student/index.php/timetable";
WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I couldn't find a way to check if above code works, however my question is:

How can you access the data(texts) you want from the page? I want to get the subject names. Part of the html looks like this :

[image: html]

Comment: Do you need to do this via c#? I think its a lot easier to read the data via javascript. If you dont need the data for further actions in c#, you could do it with a simple javascript snippet.

Comment: Use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML

Comment: what about the documentation of [that software](https://www.kamar.nz/)? i mean did you check the documentation of the webapp  to find any export function that may be already available? that would greatly simplify your job...

Comment: It's probably a longshot, hence posting a comment not answer, but have you considered using something like Selenium? My guess is that you don't want a browser flying around, but it would make this task much simpler.

Comment: Thanks to all you guys, helped me make decisions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this: one would be regexp matching and taking the contents of the tags and another would be to just use HtmlAgilityPack library.

If you don't need to do it in C# I would strongly recommend a different language like Python or Perl. It seems to me that you are trying to scrape the data and in this case I strongly recommend to use the Scrapy framework from Python if possible. It's the best tool I encountered for scraping and you can use XPath to get your data easily. Here is the [link to Scrapy's website](http://scrapy.org/).

Comment: Thank you! I will look at them. Maybe consider python :)